# How to force the phone earpiece to be used when an external microphone (headset) is connected?

Tags: audio, microphone

I want to keep the sound output on the phone, the earpiece or the loudspeaker as it is normally when I connect an external microphone. It's detected as a headset so they're disabled as well as the microphone.

My internal microphone is dead, and I want to use this small jack microphone I have.

Is there an obscure setting, working app, or adb command for this?

I tried a few apps, but none of them worked. "Lesser AudioSwitch" got the closest. The microphone works so does the phone speakers, EXCEPT when I start a phone call, then the microphone input stops working and I'm not heard by the person I called. Which would be the main reason to use the microphone...

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Unfortunately, you can't do this on Android since android doesn't come with separate mic and sound choices. There might be solutions if your device has root access though

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't only interested in plain android settings. I'm willing to try things. Anything particular you know for a rooted phones that might work?

Comment: I donr exactly remember but i do recall seeing something similar to what you're asking for like two years ago on my old rooted tablet.